# Antonyme de polyvalent ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, travail, antonyme

Le wiktionnaire propose un sens de [polyvalent](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/polyvalent) qui s'adapte aux personnes.

> *Un employé **polyvalent**.*

[CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/antonymie/polyvalent) propose comme antonyme **monovalent**, pourtant [son sens](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/monovalent) semble bien différent, en particulier il ne s'adapterait pas aux personnes.

Pouvez-vous m'indiquer si monovalent convient ? Et s'il existe un meilleur antonyme ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tout dépend du sens qu'on veut lui donner. Si on veut dire péjorativement qu'un employé n'est pas polyvalent, *monovalent* sera bien compris comme « Ne sait faire qu'une seule chose. ».

Si, en revanche, on veut dire que l'employé n'est censé faire qu'une seule chose mais que c'est normal, *spécialisé* est plus pertinent, comme le dit [jlliagre](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14457/82).

En bon logiciens, notons toutefois que la négation de *polyvalent* est *non-polyvalent*.

Answer (score 11):

Monovalent ne parait pas adapté en effet, les domaines d'utilisation de cet adjectif étant essentiellement [la chimie, la médecine et la linguistique](http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/advanced.exe?8;s=2072300850;). J'utiliserais:

> Un employé spécialisé.

Puisque cet employé n'est pas polyvalent, c'est qu'il est spécialisé dans un métier bien précis qu'il conviendrait de préciser.

---

Edit: Parler d'un « employé monovalent » pour désigner péjorativement un employé inapte à accomplir des tâches variées fera ouvrir de grands yeux à la plupart de vos interlocuteurs, cette combinaison étant essentiellement inconnue en français.

Un employé qui n'est ni spécialisé ni polyvalent risque plutôt d'être traité simplement de « bon à rien » ...

Answer (score 3):

"**Monovalent**" est clairement un mot trop technique pour être utilisé dans ce contexte.

Soit le sens du mot recherché est positif - "qui excelle dans une tâche particulière" - et on utilisera le terme **spécialisé**

Soit le sens est plus péjoratif, et on peut utiliser le mot usuel (appartenant sans doute au registre familier) **monotâche**

C'est à mon avis ce dernier mot qui a le plus de chance de répondre à la question.

Answer (score 1):

*Exception culturelle française :*

Dans l'Administration française un *agent polyvalent* (on est *agent* dans une administration et *employé* dans une entreprise) est un  fonctionnaire des impôts *spécialiste* du contrôle des entreprises :

> **Polyvalent** ...  § 4 du Robert   (personne + spécialiste) : Agent des contributions chargé de vérifier les comptes des entreprises.

Il est en effet polyvalent dans le sens où il a un pouvoir de contrôle et de vérification étendu.

C'est un cas apparent *d'[oxymore](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxymore)* : Un agent polyvalent spécialiste des *[PME](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petite_et_moyenne_entreprise)* !

Il n'y a pas d'antonyme pour le Robert, *[Reverso](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/polyvalent)* indique *différencié*, mais *[jiliagre](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14457/82)* a fourni la réponse usuelle pour un employé.

Answer (score 0):

Le terme polyvalent est souvent utilisé dans le sens de étendu, général, voire universel. Si par exemple on sous-entend l'étendue des connaissances techniques d'un ouvrier polyvalent,  le terme débutant pourrait être un bon antonyme. Dans d'autres contextes, le terme limité pourrait être utilisé. Il semble cependant plus aisé, en général, de trouver une locution qu'un mot.

Comment: Plutôt que "débutant" je suggérerait "spécialisé", un ouvrier pouvant être polyvalent sans être particulièrement expérimenté.

Answer (score 0):

L'antonyme adapté de polyvalent dépend nettement du contexte dans lequel il est inséré.
Polyvalent, notamment dans le monde du travail et de l'entreprise, a un sens proche d'adaptable, flexible ou multi-tâche. Rigide ou inadaptable sont des antonymes corrects dans ce cas de figure. J'ai une désaffection pour multi-tâche/mono-tâche dans ce cas de figure, car une personne monotâche peut avoir des compétences diverses, mais n'exercer qu'une tâche après l'autre au lieu d'un multi-tâche apte à déporter son attention sur plusieurs tâche simultanées. NB : le multi-tâche peut entretenir plusieurs tâches ne relevant que d'une seule et même compétence.
Tout dépend du contexte ;)

Le terme monovalent ne s'utilise guère en parlant de qualité humaine. Un paramètre est monovalent, cela signifie qu'il ne peut avoir qu'une seule valeur à un instant donné (ce qui ne l'empêche pas d'en changer. On utilise plus souvent l'adjectif monovalué pour qualifier cette propriété). L'usage de monovalent reste restreint au domaine mathématique et scientifique, ce qui n'en fait pas un bon antonyme.